# @nest/jwt decode function sending [object Object] as string insted of real object

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs

I am trying to verify and decode a token send via api using following code:

**To verify**

```js
const user = this.jwtService.verify(token);
```

**To decode**

```js
const user = this.jwtService.decode(token);
const user = this.jwtService.decode(token, { json: true });
```

In each instance I am getting string output from functions `[object Object]`.

**Node version**: v12.13.1

**Nestjs version**: v6.7.2

**@nestjs/jwt version**: v6.1.1

**OS**: MacOS

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked what `token` is before you decode it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake fixed it. Was passing `payload.toString()` in `this.jwtService.sign()`.